# How to ipv6 in integer in mysql databases?

Tags: mysql, mariadb, ipv6, ipv4

I have one table where I store ip address. For faster access I store ip int also. This is the table structure.

```
CREATE TABLE `ipv6_test` (
  `ip_string` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ip_int` double DEFAULT null
) ;
```

I have used following method to get integer version of ip address.

```
new BigInteger(1, com.google.common.net.InetAddresses.forString(ip).getAddress());
```

Everything was working fine for ipv4 addresses, but my code started failing while storing ipv6 addresses.

How to store BigInteger in mysql database? 
I'm thinking to use VARBINARY. Can I create index on VARBINARY column?

How is the VARBINARY's performance compared to index on integer?

Comment: Why `ip_int` is DOUBLE? Even while not paying attention that it is approximate - anycase it cannot receive 128 bits of data.

Answer (score 3):

[INET6_ATON](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/inet6_aton/) converts to a varbinary(16) for IPv4 + IPv6 storage.

Yes you can use VARBINARY as indexes. Its effectively a VARCHAR without character encoding.  Its probably a bit slower than integers but ints can't do the same job. You probably won't notice it so don't prematurely optimize. Its only 16 characters maximum so its not much.

If you want to keep an text version for easy retrieval create a [generated column](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/generated-columns/) converting the varbinary back.

Comment: Since MariaDB-10.5, there is a [INET6](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/inet6/) datatype for the benefits of compact storage, and the readability of text version in retreival.